# Exporting dataset to excel error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: c#, excel

I am having trouble in exporting to excel and it crashes out at the .set_Value function.

It seems to work if I change object[,] to string[,] but by doing this I lose the formatting.

Anyone Help?

Comment: Perhaps you could post the offending code?

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing '`null`' for missing parameters rather than `System.Reflection.Missing.Value` ?

Comment: I am using the S.R.Missing.Value and still getting this error :(

Answer (score 0):

I am passing `Missing.Value` but I have discovered what was the cause of this particular failure. The object[,] had a `=` sign as first character in some cells which caused Excel to fail so I checked for column type string and checked value `if substring(0,1) == "="` then add a `'` in front of `=` sign.